# flex 4 render html

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

can anybody advise me a free component that normally renders html in flex **4**?
For example i need to render html such as:

```
<p class="Normal" style="color:#FF0000; text-decoration: underline;"><span class="" style="text-decoration: underline;">1.TESTgh</span></p>
```

i found iframe-flex. but it doesn't work in fourth version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a project [TLFX](http://code.google.com/p/tlfx/) that extends TLF to add nicer HTML support but they are not event in alpha.

You can write your own HTML cleaner by porting some Java HTML cleaners (this will let you transform HTML into XML) and then generate TLF markup from that XML. That's what we do in our project.

If you know that incoming HTML is a valid XML, you can skip cleaner state.

Unfortunately I don't know any ready-to-use solution.